# AWS generate dynamic credential for S3 folder level access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm new to AWS and still figuring out how to do things.

Part of my web application is using AWS S3 for file storage, but I want each user to be only able to access specific folders(for CRUD) in the bucket.
The backend server will track what folders the user will be able to access.

I know it is possible to define policies that allow access to specific folders(by matching prefix of objects), but can I generate these policies dynamically and get credentials with these policies attached (probably with Cognito?). So that these credentials could be passed to client-side to enable access to S3 folders.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do that and what services are required to achieve this.

Comment: did you take a look at [presigned URLs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls)? They can be used to create temporarily valid URLs to download files, which you could then only serve to a specific user. I believe you can also generate presigned POSTs should you need user/client file uploads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your view, each time you want to share a file with one of your users, you should check your database about their permissions( folders they have access) and if logical things on your side are correct, generate a presigned URL for access to that object.

[image]

**How presigned URL works.**

When you generate a presigned URL for accessing to an object, you can set the time limit too, it means after that time, the URL not work and expired.

For more information about the presigned URL, read the following documents on Amazon Web services website:

[Generate a Pre-signed Object URL Using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

[Generate a Pre-signed Object URL Using AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html)

Also, if you want to create users and assign the right policy for access them to their folder you can follow these instructions:

You can use the IAM API to creating a user for each of your users, and attach the right policy for each of them.
For example, for creating the new user, you should use the following API

```
/* The following create-user command creates an IAM user named Bob in the current account. */

 var params = {
  UserName: "Bob"
 };
 iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    User: {
     Arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob", 
     CreateDate: <Date Representation>, 
     Path: "/", 
     UserId: "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE", 
     UserName: "Bob"
    }
   }
   */
 });
```

For more info about the Create user API, read the following

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html

After creating a user, you should create a policy for each of them with CreatePolicy API.

```
var params = {
  PolicyDocument: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  PolicyName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Description: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Path: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
iam.createPolicy(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

For more info about the Create policy read the following doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePolicy.html

And finally, you should assign the policy you created before to each user by the AttachUserPolicy API.

```
/* The following command attaches the AWS managed policy named AdministratorAccess to the IAM user named Alice. */

     var params = {
      PolicyArn: "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess", 
      UserName: "Alice"
     };
     iam.attachUserPolicy(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else     console.log(data);           // successful response
     });
```

For more info about the AttachUserPolicy API read the following doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_AttachUserPolicy.html

The last part is about the which policy you should create and assign to each of them; we use the following policy for listing objects in each folder:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
  "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}
}
```

And the following policy for actions in each folder:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:*"],
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/David/*"]
}
```

For more detailed info about that policies read the following article by  **Jim Scharf**:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, but I'm looking for the support to allow users to list and delete objects as well. Perhaps I should do that on backend server? (user send delete request to my server, server do the authentication and send delete request to S3 on user's behalf)?

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. Thank you so much. That would also definitely helpful to others.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: So I need to create IAM user for each user in my application, attach policy for it, and create access key for each user. After passing the keys to users, they can access S3 programmatically, is that right?

Comment: One more question, in my application, the folders in bucket is not per user specific, though the backend server is implemented logic to decide whether the user has permission to access it, which means, by doing this way, I have to constantly add and remove policy to IAM users when some changes are made to folders and object. It makes things a little bit ugly. That's why I came up with the idea of generating dynamical credentials in the first place.

Comment: I was wondering if there are other ways to do it, like some temporary credential allow user to access a folder but such credential is only valid for a period of time, or invalidated once user logout.

Comment: As you mentioned that not a good idea, and it's the main reason I preferred the pre-signed URL method at first. I think with the pre-signed URL and some logical check on your app side, you can achieve all of your needs without creating/updating/removing users and policies.

Comment: This works, but it also relies on the developers to do things correctly. Probably a good idea to include an IAM policy to limit users to the s3 objects they can access as well.

Comment: @JackMarchetti Let's imagine we have an app with a thousand users. Do we want to create a policy and user for each of them on AWS end?

Comment: @RezaMousavi technically yes. If you use something like Cognito it can do this for you. Or do something with STS and AssumeRole and inject the policy at that point. (this  then too relies on developers injecting the policy though)

Comment: @RezaMousavi I could be wrong though. Been working on something like this the past few days. ha