# AWS S3 - secure URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Trying to find a best practice to securely download contents from s3 on a SPA? Presigned URL seems to be one of the options. But whoever can get hold of that URL can access the contents. Is there a way to protect the presigned URL with an extra layer of security? Like to ensure the right person is accessing the files. Just a note, we use a third party IDP and not cognito.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS generate dynamic credential for S3 folder level access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687127/aws-generate-dynamic-credential-for-s3-folder-level-access)

Comment: You can do this by limiting the validity of the download URL to a short time frame. Sure, the user could share the URL with whoever on social media who could download the object during that time, but your user could equally just download the file and share it with whoever too.

Comment: If you really want to up the security you can Federate your existing users IDP with Cognito Identity Pools (Federated Identities) and generate a session policy for the user, that not only limit the download to a specific time frame but also to their IP address, and then use the credentials for the Federated user (which has the session policy attached) to generate the signed URL.

Comment: @hephalump Thanks! May have to explore this option.